# Statistics of US/Europe Businesses, Advertising Agencies Specifically

Tags: data-request, companies

I've been searching furiously and the closest I came across was this for the Europe http://marketing-advertising-the-media.europages.co.uk/business-directory-europe/did-22/Marketing-Advertising-the-Media.html and some 20 years old statistics from https://explore.data.gov/

Does anyone know if there's such database?

Comment: People will be better able to answer your question if you list specific statistics you are looking for. It also helps to write your question as a complete thought instead of continuing it from the headline.

Comment: Just how many agencies there are, nothing more, even though number of their employees have would be nice as well.

Comment: You can actually edit the question to add that information. The more clear your question is, the more likely someone will be to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

Gut feel, you will have to dig this data up *country by country*.

This list should be fairly up to date for the UK.
http://www.ipa.co.uk/framework/sections/agency/agencies.aspx?display=list&menu=open (something like import.io or scraperwiki will help you turn the page into `data` - I don't think they have an API)

I found this http://eaca.adforum.com/search/agency/idCountry/783 which has a variety of search options for agencies. Again, it is a site not a db. So you would have to use a scraper of some variety. There is still no guarantee of accuracy or completeness.